# How to efficiently calculate a running standard deviation

Tags: statistics

I have an array of lists of numbers, e.g.:

```
[0] (0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.03)
[1] (0.00, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02)
[2] (0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02)
     ...
[n] (0.01, 0.00, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03)
```

I would like to efficiently calculate the mean and standard deviation at each index of a list, across all array elements.

To do the mean, I have been looping through the array and summing the value at a given index of a list. At the end, I divide each value in my "averages list" by `n` (I am working with a population, not a sample from the population).

To do the standard deviation, I loop through again, now that I have the mean calculated.

I would like to avoid going through the array twice, once for the mean and then once for the standard deviation (after I have a mean).

Is there an efficient method for calculating both values, only going through the array once? Any code in an interpreted language (e.g., Perl or Python) or pseudocode is fine.

Comment: Different language, but same algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895929/how-do-i-determine-the-standard-deviation-stddev-of-a-set-of-values

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that algorithm out. Sounds like what I need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right answer, dmckee. I'd like to give you the "best answer" checkmark, if you'd like to take a moment to add your answer below (if you'd like the points).

Comment: Also, there are several examples at http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Standard_Deviation

Comment: Wikipedia has a Python implementation http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#On-line_algorithm

Comment: I'd like an answer that I can just copy paste to my code in numpy. My input is a matrix of size [N, 1] where N is the number of data points and I already have computed the running mean and I assuming we have computed the running std/variance, how to update we the new batch of data. Context: https://github.com/brando90/ultimate-anatome/issues/10

Comment: Perhaps try this existing numpy implementation of Welford's algorithm: https://github.com/a-mitani/welford

Comment: @AlexReynolds I was thinking to translate it to pytorch however...so the copy paste part was needed...but perhaps that can be used for that or just to plug in and play....thanks will see it later.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

The answer is to use Welford's algorithm, which is very clearly defined after the "naive methods" in:

- Wikipedia: [Algorithms for calculating variance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance)

It's more numerically stable than either the two-pass or online simple sum of squares collectors suggested in other responses.  The stability only really matters when you have lots of values that are close to each other as they lead to what is known as "[catastrophic cancellation](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/91float/)" in the floating point literature.

You might also want to brush up on the difference between dividing by the number of samples (N) and N-1 in the variance calculation (squared deviation).  Dividing by N-1 leads to an unbiased estimate of variance from the sample, whereas dividing by N on average underestimates variance (because it doesn't take into account the variance between the sample mean and the true mean).

Comment: But it is also slower, so it is a tradeoff between numerically stability and performance (or in other words, it depends). *"...might not be as efficient because of the division operation inside the loop."*

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer. As @PeterMortensen says, adding a division operator inside the loop is too slow to be practical on modern hardware. When models like GPT are run on NVIDIA GPUs, Jonathan's answer is used by default (see the [LayerNorm kernel](https://github.com/NVIDIA/FasterTransformer/blob/main/src/fastertransformer/kernels/layernorm_kernels.cu) in FasterTransformer). In the rare case that more accuracy is needed, the two-pass algorithm is used.

Answer (score 82):

The basic answer is to accumulate the sum of both *x* (call it 'sum_x1') and *x*<sup>2</sup> (call it 'sum_x2') as you go.  The value of the standard deviation is then:

```
stdev = sqrt((sum_x2 / n) - (mean * mean))
```

where

```
mean = sum_x / n
```

This is the sample standard deviation; you get the population standard deviation using 'n' instead of 'n - 1' as the divisor.

You may need to worry about the numerical stability of taking the difference between two large numbers if you are dealing with large samples.  Go to the external references in other answers (Wikipedia, etc) for more information.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. It's the best and fastest way, assuming precision errors are not a problem.

Comment: I decided to go with Welford's Algorithm as it performs more reliably with the same computational overhead.

Comment: This is a simplified version of the answer and may give non-real results depending on the input (i.e., when sum_x2 < sum_x1 * sum_x1). To ensure a valid real result, go with `sd = sqrt(((n * sum_x2) - (sum_x1 * sum_x1)) / (n * (n - 1)))

Comment: @Dan: am I missing something?  Your expression appears to be different from mine - as in, guaranteed to produce a different result - because you've multiplied sum_x2 by n but not made a compensating multiplication of sum_x1 * sum_x1?

Comment: @Dan points out a valid issue - the formula above breaks down for x>1 because you end up taking the sqrt of a negative number. The Knuth approach is: sqrt((sum_x2 / n) - (mean * mean)) where mean = (sum_x / n).

Comment: @flies: The answer has changed since I left that comment 1 year ago and Greg left his over two months ago. The formula used to be sqrt((sum_x2 - sum_x1 * sum_x1) / (n - 1)), which, unless I'm mistaken, was actually incorrect.

Comment: Dividing by N gives the maximum likelihood estimate of variance, but it's biased to the low side because it uses the sample mean rather than the true mean.  Dividing by N - 1 gives you an unbiased estimate of the variance.

Comment: @UriLoya — you've not said anything about how you are calculating the values.  However, if you use `int` in C to store the sum of squares, you run into overflow problems with the values you list.

Answer (score 62):

Here is a literal pure Python translation of the [Welford's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm) implementation from John D. Cook’s excellent *[Accurately computing running variance](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html)* article:

#### File *[running_stats.py](https://github.com/liyanage/python-modules/blob/master/running_stats.py)*

```
import math

class RunningStats:

    def __init__(self):
        self.n = 0
        self.old_m = 0
        self.new_m = 0
        self.old_s = 0
        self.new_s = 0

    def clear(self):
        self.n = 0

    def push(self, x):
        self.n += 1

        if self.n == 1:
            self.old_m = self.new_m = x
            self.old_s = 0
        else:
            self.new_m = self.old_m + (x - self.old_m) / self.n
            self.new_s = self.old_s + (x - self.old_m) * (x - self.new_m)

            self.old_m = self.new_m
            self.old_s = self.new_s

    def mean(self):
        return self.new_m if self.n else 0.0

    def variance(self):
        return self.new_s / (self.n - 1) if self.n > 1 else 0.0

    def standard_deviation(self):
        return math.sqrt(self.variance())
```

Usage:

```
rs = RunningStats()
rs.push(17.0)
rs.push(19.0)
rs.push(24.0)

mean = rs.mean()
variance = rs.variance()
stdev = rs.standard_deviation()

print(f'Mean: {mean}, Variance: {variance}, Std. Dev.: {stdev}')
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it's the only one that is both correct and shows the algorithm, with reference to Knuth.

Comment: To the contributors who recently edited this answer, I had to reject your edit because I think it was incorrect. The edit removed the n == 1 special case in the push method, but I think that that case is required for correct results after the clear() method is used, I suspect you overlooked that.

Answer (score 26):

Perhaps not what you were asking, but ... If you use a [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy) array, it will do the work for you, efficiently:

```
from numpy import array

nums = array(((0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.03),
              (0.00, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02),
              (0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02),
              (0.01, 0.00, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03)))

print nums.std(axis=1)
# [ 0.0116619   0.00979796  0.00632456  0.01788854]

print nums.mean(axis=1)
# [ 0.022  0.018  0.02   0.02 ]
```

Answer (score 19):

The [Python runstats Module](http://www.grantjenks.com/blog/portfolio-post/python-runstats-module/) is for just this sort of thing. [Install runstats](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/runstats) from PyPI:

```
pip install runstats
```

Runstats summaries can produce the mean, variance, standard deviation, skewness, and kurtosis  in a single pass of data. We can use this to create your "running" version.

```
from runstats import Statistics

stats = [Statistics() for num in range(len(data[0]))]

for row in data:

    for index, val in enumerate(row):
        stats[index].push(val)

    for index, stat in enumerate(stats):
        print 'Index', index, 'mean:', stat.mean()
        print 'Index', index, 'standard deviation:', stat.stddev()
```

Statistics summaries are based on the Knuth and Welford method for computing standard deviation in one pass as described in the Art of Computer Programming, Vol 2, p. 232, 3rd edition. The benefit of this is numerically stable and accurate results.

**Disclaimer:** I am the author the Python runstats module.

Comment: Nice module. It'd be interesting if there was a `Statistics` has a `.pop` method so rolling statistics could also be calculated.

Comment: @GustavoBezerra ``runstats`` does not maintain an internal list of values so I'm not sure that's possible. But pull requests are welcome.

Answer (score 9):

[Statistics::Descriptive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Statistics::Descriptive) is a very decent Perl module for these types of calculations:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use Statistics::Descriptive qw( :all );

my $data = [
    [ 0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.03 ],
    [ 0.00, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02 ],
    [ 0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02 ],
    [ 0.01, 0.00, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03 ],
];

my $stat = Statistics::Descriptive::Full->new;
# You also have the option of using sparse data structures

for my $ref ( @$data ) {
    $stat->add_data( @$ref );
    printf "Running mean: %f\n", $stat->mean;
    printf "Running stdev: %f\n", $stat->standard_deviation;
}
__END__
```

Output:

```
Running mean: 0.022000
Running stdev: 0.013038
Running mean: 0.020000
Running stdev: 0.011547
Running mean: 0.020000
Running stdev: 0.010000
Running mean: 0.020000
Running stdev: 0.012566
```

Comment: What is "`__END__`" for? Is it necessary?

Comment: I am using it to mark the end of the script. Please refer to "[Perl tokens you should know](https://www.perl.com/article/24/2013/5/11/Perl-tokens-you-should-know/#end-data)"

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at [PDL](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDL/) (pronounced "piddle!").

This is the Perl Data Language which is designed for high precision mathematics and scientific computing.

Here is an example using your figures....

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use PDL;

my $figs = pdl [
    [0.01, 0.01, 0.02, 0.04, 0.03],
    [0.00, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02],
    [0.01, 0.02, 0.02, 0.03, 0.02],
    [0.01, 0.00, 0.01, 0.05, 0.03],
];

my ( $mean, $prms, $median, $min, $max, $adev, $rms ) = statsover( $figs );

say "Mean scores:     ", $mean;
say "Std dev? (adev): ", $adev;
say "Std dev? (prms): ", $prms;
say "Std dev? (rms):  ", $rms;
```

Which produces:

```
Mean scores:     [0.022 0.018 0.02 0.02]
Std dev? (adev): [0.0104 0.0072 0.004 0.016]
Std dev? (prms): [0.013038405 0.010954451 0.0070710678 0.02]
Std dev? (rms):  [0.011661904 0.009797959 0.0063245553 0.017888544]
```

Have a look at [PDL::Primitive](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PDL/Basic/Primitive/primitive.pd) for more information on the *statsover* function.  This seems to suggest that ADEV is the "standard deviation".

However, it maybe PRMS (which Sinan's Statistics::Descriptive example show) or RMS (which [ars's NumPy example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174984/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-running-standard-deviation/1175491#1175491) shows).  I guess one of these three must be right ;-)

For more PDL information, have a look at:

- [pdl.perl.org](http://pdl.perl.org)  (official PDL page).
- [PDL quick reference guide on PerlMonks](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=587436)
- [Dr. Dobb's article on PDL](http://www.ddj.com/184410442)
- [PDL Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pdl/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Wikipedia entry for PDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Data_Language)
- [SourceForge project page for PDL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdl/)

Comment: This is not a running calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Unless your array is zillions of elements long, don't worry about looping through it twice. The code is simple and easily tested.

My preference would be to use the [NumPy](https://numpy.org/) array maths extension to convert your array of arrays into a NumPy 2D array and get the standard deviation directly:

```
>>> x = [ [ 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5 ], [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ] ] * 10
>>> import numpy
>>> a = numpy.array(x)
>>> a.std(axis=0)
array([ 1. ,  1. ,  0.5,  1.5,  1.5,  1.5])
>>> a.mean(axis=0)
array([ 2. ,  3. ,  4.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5])
```

If that's not an option and you need a pure Python solution, keep reading...

If your array is

```
x = [
      [ 1, 2, 4, 3, 4, 5 ],
      [ 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ],
      ....
]
```

Then the standard deviation is:

```
d = len(x[0])
n = len(x)
sum_x = [ sum(v[i] for v in x) for i in range(d) ]
sum_x2 = [ sum(v[i]**2 for v in x) for i in range(d) ]
std_dev = [ sqrt((sx2 - sx**2)/N)  for sx, sx2 in zip(sum_x, sum_x2) ]
```

If you are determined to loop through your array only once, the running sums can be combined.

```
sum_x  = [ 0 ] * d
sum_x2 = [ 0 ] * d
for v in x:
   for i, t in enumerate(v):
   sum_x[i] += t
   sum_x2[i] += t**2
```

This isn't nearly as elegant as the list comprehension solution above.

Comment: I do actually have to deal with zillions of numbers, which is what motivates my need for an efficient solution. Thanks!

Comment: its not about how big the data set is, its about how OFTEN, i have to do 3500 different standard deviation calculations over 500 elements on each calculation per second

Answer (score 3):

I like to express the update this way:

```
def running_update(x, N, mu, var):
    '''
        @arg x: the current data sample
        @arg N : the number of previous samples
        @arg mu: the mean of the previous samples
        @arg var : the variance over the previous samples
        @retval (N+1, mu', var') -- updated mean, variance and count
    '''
    N = N + 1
    rho = 1.0/N
    d = x - mu
    mu += rho*d
    var += rho*((1-rho)*d**2 - var)
    return (N, mu, var)
```

so that a one-pass function would look like this:

```
def one_pass(data):
    N = 0
    mu = 0.0
    var = 0.0
    for x in data:
        N = N + 1
        rho = 1.0/N
        d = x - mu
        mu += rho*d
        var += rho*((1-rho)*d**2 - var)
        # could yield here if you want partial results
   return (N, mu, var)
```

note that this is calculating the sample variance (1/N), not the unbiased estimate of the population variance (which uses a 1/(N-1) normalzation factor).  Unlike the other answers, the variable, `var`, that is tracking the running variance does not grow in proportion to the number of samples. At all times it is just the variance of the set of samples seen so far (there is no final "dividing by n" in getting the variance).

In a class it would look like this:

```
class RunningMeanVar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.N = 0
        self.mu = 0.0
        self.var = 0.0
    def push(self, x):
        self.N = self.N + 1
        rho = 1.0/N
        d = x-self.mu
        self.mu += rho*d
        self.var += + rho*((1-rho)*d**2-self.var)
    # reset, accessors etc. can be setup as you see fit
```

This also works for weighted samples:

```
def running_update(w, x, N, mu, var):
    '''
        @arg w: the weight of the current sample
        @arg x: the current data sample
        @arg mu: the mean of the previous N sample
        @arg var : the variance over the previous N samples
        @arg N : the number of previous samples
        @retval (N+w, mu', var') -- updated mean, variance and count
    '''
    N = N + w
    rho = w/N
    d = x - mu
    mu += rho*d
    var += rho*((1-rho)*d**2 - var)
    return (N, mu, var)
```

Comment: But division can be a very expensive operation? Perhaps address that in the answer? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Comment: @PeterMortensen if the application is one where getting rid of a division operation per sample in the ensemble makes or breaks your algorithm, then, yeah, you might need to look into a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a "one-liner", spread over multiple lines, in functional programming style:

```py
def variance(data, opt=0):
    return (lambda (m2, i, _): m2 / (opt + i - 1))(
        reduce(
            lambda (m2, i, avg), x:
            (
                m2 + (x - avg) ** 2 * i / (i + 1),
                i + 1,
                avg + (x - avg) / (i + 1)
            ),
            data,
            (0, 0, 0)))
```

Comment: What does it do? Are there a lot of unnecessary computations or not? For example, compared to maintaining a sum of values and a sum of squares of values?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: I don't remember what algorithm this was anymore...

Answer (score 1):

As the following answer describes:
*[Does Pandas, SciPy, or NumPy provide a cumulative standard deviation function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369663/does-pandas-scipy-numpy-provide-a-cumulative-standard-deviation-function)*

The Python Pandas module contains a method to calculate the running or [cumulative standard deviation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.expanding_std.html). For that, you'll have to convert your data into a Pandas dataframe (or a series if it is one-dimensional), but there are functions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a practical example of how you could implement a running standard deviation with Python and [NumPy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NumPy):

```
a = np.arange(1, 10)
s = 0
s2 = 0
for i in range(0, len(a)):
    s += a[i]
    s2 += a[i] ** 2
    n = (i + 1)
    m = s / n
    std = np.sqrt((s2 / n) - (m * m))
    print(std, np.std(a[:i + 1]))
```

This will print out the calculated standard deviation and a check standard deviation calculated with NumPy:

> ```
> 0.0 0.0
> 0.5 0.5
> 0.8164965809277263 0.816496580927726
> 1.118033988749895 1.118033988749895
> 1.4142135623730951 1.4142135623730951
> 1.707825127659933 1.707825127659933
> 2.0 2.0
> 2.29128784747792 2.29128784747792
> 2.5819888974716116 2.581988897471611
> ```

I am just using the formula described in this thread:

```
stdev = sqrt((sum_x2 / n) - (mean * mean))
```

Answer (score 1):

Responding to [Charlie Parker's 2021 question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174984/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-running-standard-deviation#comment123972361_1174984):

> I'd like an answer that I can just copy paste to my code in numpy. My input is a matrix of size [N, 1] where N is the number of data points and I already have computed the running mean and I assuming we have computed the running std/variance, how to update we the new batch of data.

Here we have two implementations of a function that takes the original mean, original variance and original size and the new sample and returns the total mean and total variance of the combined original and new sample (to get the standard deviation, just take variance's square root by using `**(1/2)`). The first uses NumPy, and the second one uses [Welford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford%27s_online_algorithm). You may choose the one that best applies to your case.

```
def mean_and_variance_update_numpy(previous_mean, previous_var, previous_size, sample_to_append):
    if type(sample_to_append) is np.matrix:
        sample_to_append = sample_to_append.A1
    else:
        sample_to_append = sample_to_append.flatten()
    sample_to_append_mean = np.mean(sample_to_append)
    sample_to_append_size = len(sample_to_append)
    total_size = previous_size+sample_to_append_size
    total_mean = (previous_mean*previous_size+sample_to_append_mean*sample_to_append_size)/total_size
    total_var = (((previous_var+(total_mean-previous_mean)**2)*previous_size)+((np.var(sample_to_append)+(sample_to_append_mean-tm)**2)*sample_to_append_size))/total_size
    return (total_mean, total_var)

def mean_and_variance_update_welford(previous_mean, previous_var, previous_size, sample_to_append):
    if type(sample_to_append) is np.matrix:
        sample_to_append = sample_to_append.A1
    else:
        sample_to_append = sample_to_append.flatten()
    pos = previous_size
    mean = previous_mean
    v = previous_var*previous_size
    for value in sample_to_append:
        pos += 1
        mean_next = mean + (value - mean) / pos
        v = v + (value - mean)*(value - mean_next)
        mean = mean_next
    return (mean, v/pos)
```

Let's check if it works:

```py
import numpy as np

def mean_and_variance_udpate_numpy:
    ...
def mean_and_variance_udpate_welford:
    ...

# Making the samples and results deterministic
np.random.seed(0)

# Our initial sample has 100 samples, we want to append 10
n0, n1 = 100, 10

# Using np.matrix only, because it was in the question. 'np.array' is more common
s0 = np.matrix(1e3+np.random.random_sample(n0)*1e-3).T
s1 = np.matrix(1e3+np.random.random_sample(n1)*1e-3).T

# Precalculating our mean and var for initial sample:
s0mean, s0var = np.mean(s0), np.var(s0)

# Calculating mean and variance for s0+s1 using our NumPy updater
mean_and_variance_update_numpy(s0mean, s0var, len(s0), s1)
# (1000.0004826329636, 8.24577589696613e-08)

# Calculating mean and variance for s0+s1 using our Welford updater
mean_and_variance_update_welford(s0mean, s0var, len(s0), s1)
# (1000.0004826329634, 8.245775896913623e-08)

# Similar results, now checking with NumPy's calculation over the concatenation of s0 and s1
s0s1 = np.concatenate([s0,s1])
(np.mean(s0s1), np.var(s0s1))
# (1000.0004826329638, 8.245775896917313e-08)
```

Here the three results are closer:

```
# np(s0s1)        (1000.0004826329638, 8.245775896917313e-08)
# np(s0)updnp(s1) (1000.0004826329636, 8.245775896966130e-08)
# np(s0)updwf(s1) (1000.0004826329634, 8.245775896913623e-08)
```

It is possible to see that the results are very similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
n=int(raw_input("Enter no. of terms:"))

L=[]

for i in range (1,n+1):

    x=float(raw_input("Enter term:"))

    L.append(x)

sum=0

for i in range(n):

    sum=sum+L[i]

avg=sum/n

sumdev=0

for j in range(n):

    sumdev=sumdev+(L[j]-avg)**2

dev=(sumdev/n)**0.5

print "Standard deviation is", dev
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? It seems to be a very naive implementation. From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26716417/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: And it does not answer the question: *"I would like to avoid going through the array twice"*.

Answer (score 0):

Figure I could jump on the old bandwagon. This should work with rbg values

Adapted from
https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2148949

```py
import numpy as np


class IterativeNormStats():

    def __init__(self):
        """uint64 max is 18446744073709551615
        256**2 = 65536

        so we can store 18446744073709551615 / 65536 = 281,474,976,710,656
        images before running into overflow issues. I think we'll be ok
        """
        self.n = 0
        self.rgb_sum = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.uint64)
        self.rgb_sq_sum = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.uint64)

    def update(self, img_arr):
        rgbs = np.reshape(img_arr, (-1, 3)).astype(np.uint64)
        self.n += rgbs.shape[0]
        self.rgb_sum += np.sum(rgbs, axis=0)
        self.rgb_sq_sum += np.sum(np.square(rgbs), axis=0)

    def mean(self):
        return self.rgb_sum / self.n

    def std(self):
        return np.sqrt((self.rgb_sq_sum / self.n) - np.square(self.rgb_sum / self.n))


def test_IterativeNormStats():
    img_a = np.ones((10, 10, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * (1, 2, 3)
    img_b = np.ones((10, 10, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * (2, 4, 6)
    img_c = np.ones((10, 10, 3), dtype=np.uint8) * (3, 6, 9)
    ins = IterativeNormStats()
    for i in range(1000):
        for img in [img_a, img_b, img_c]:
            ins.update(img)

    x = np.vstack([
        np.reshape(img_a, (-1, 3)),
        np.reshape(img_b, (-1, 3)),
        np.reshape(img_c, (-1, 3)),
    ]*1000)
    expected_mean = np.mean(x, axis=0)
    expected_std = np.std(x, axis=0)

    print(expected_mean)
    print(ins.mean())
    print(expected_std)
    print(ins.std())
    assert np.allclose(ins.mean(), expected_mean)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_IterativeNormStats()
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across thee [`welford`](https://pypi.org/project/welford/) package that's pretty simple to use:

```
pip install welford
```

Then

```py
import numpy as np
from welford import Welford

# Initialize Welford object
w = Welford()

# Input data samples sequentialy
w.add(np.array([0, 100]))
w.add(np.array([1, 110]))
w.add(np.array([2, 120]))

# output
print(w.mean)  # mean --> [  1. 110.]
print(w.var_s)  # sample variance --> [1, 100]
print(w.var_p)  # population variance --> [ 0.6666 66.66]

# You can add other samples after calculating variances.
w.add(np.array([3, 130]))
w.add(np.array([4, 140]))

# output with added samples
print(w.mean)  # mean --> [  2. 120.]
print(w.var_s)  # sample variance --> [  2.5 250. ]
print(w.var_p)  # population variance --> [  2. 200.]
```

Notes:

- Unlike most othere answers you can feed a `Welford` object a Numpy array directly

  - You can even add multiple with `Welford.add_all(...)`
  - You can merge independent computations with `w1.merge(w2)`
- You should choose `var_p` or `var_s` depending on which one you want to use ([Population and Sample variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance))
- As said, those are *variances* so you should use `np.sqrt` to get the associated *standard deviation*

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple implementation in python:

```
class RunningStats:
    def __init__(self):
        self.mean_x_square = 0
        self.mean_x = 0
        self.n = 0

    def update(self, x):
        self.mean_x_square = (self.mean_x_square * self.n + x ** 2) / (self.n + 1)
        self.mean_x = (self.mean_x * self.n + x) / (self.n + 1)
        self.n += 1

    def mean(self):
        return self.mean_x

    def std(self):
        return self.variance() ** 0.5

    def variance(self):
        return self.mean_x_square - self.mean_x ** 2
```

Test:

```
import numpy as np
running_stats = RunningStats()
v = [1.1, 3.5, 5, -8.1, 91]
[running_stats.update(x) for x in v]
print(running_stats.mean() - np.mean(v))
print(running_stats.std() - np.std(v))
print(running_stats.variance() - np.var(v))
```

Comment: The sum-of-squares method can introduce inaccuracies with values of different precision. Consider looking upthread for discussion by John Cook and others, which covers this problem and other algorithms that address it.