# Does Pandas, SciPy, or NumPy provide a cumulative standard deviation function?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a Pandas series. I need to get *sigma_i*, which is the standard deviation of a series up to index `i`. Is there an existing function which efficiently calculates that?

I noticed that there are the *cummax* and *cummin* functions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See `pandas.expanding_std`.

For instance:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
%matplotlib inline

data = pandas.Series(np.random.normal(size=37))

full_std = np.std(data)
expand_std = pandas.expanding_std(data, min_periods=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
expand_std.plot(ax=ax, color='k', linewidth=1.5, label='Expanded Std. Dev.')
ax.axhline(y=full_std, color='g', label='Full Value')
ax.legend()
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting -- thoughts why the last value of `expand_std` isn't exactly equal to `full_std`? Shouldn't those be equivalent?

Comment: @Vincent, different default values for the degrees of freedom parameter (`ddof`: for numpy it's 0, for pandas, it's 1)