# Standard Deviation in LINQ

Tags: linq, standard-deviation

Does LINQ model the aggregate SQL function `STDDEV()`  (standard deviation)?

If not, what is the simplest / best-practices way to calculate it?

Example:

```
  SELECT test_id, AVERAGE(result) avg, STDDEV(result) std 
    FROM tests
GROUP BY test_id
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I determine the standard deviation (stddev) of a set of values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/895929/how-do-i-determine-the-standard-deviation-stddev-of-a-set-of-values)

Comment: @Steven, you may like to revisit the accepted answer here. There are issues with the currently selected approach that people who don't scroll down and read further might not see.

Comment: Why would anyone want to do this using *LINQ*?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can make your own extension calculating it

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
       double ret = 0;
       int count = values.Count();
       if (count  > 1)
       {
          //Compute the Average
          double avg = values.Average();

          //Perform the Sum of (value-avg)^2
          double sum = values.Sum(d => (d - avg) * (d - avg));

          //Put it all together
          ret = Math.Sqrt(sum / count);
       }
       return ret;
    }
}
```

If you have a *sample* of the population rather than the whole population, then you should use `ret = Math.Sqrt(sum / (count - 1));`.

Transformed into extension from [Adding Standard Deviation to LINQ by Chris Bennett](http://www.developer.com/net/article.php/3794146/Adding-Standard-Deviation-to-LINQ.htm).

Comment: I'd make that test "values.Count() > 1", because if it's exactly 1 you'll have a divide by zero error when you calculate the return value.

Comment: Math.pow(d-avg, 2)?  I'd skip the function call and use (d-avg)*(d-avg)

Comment: The line ret = Math.Sqrt((sum) / values.Count()-1); is missing parentheses around values.Count()-1, it should be ret = Math.Sqrt(sum / (values.Count()-1));

Comment: I was searching for this and it took me a while to figure out how to use the extension, but here is the way to apply the methods given above: `stdev = g.Select(o => o.number).StdDev()`.

Comment: Downside of this is that evaluates the input twice which is discouraged for `IEnumerable<T>` parameters.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Rozhkov - Why did you remove the `- 1`? According to [this](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Stdev-S-Function.html) the `- 1` is required.

Comment: Is there a way to do this similar to a moving average as in: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23493727/75129

Answer (score 78):

Dynami's answer works but makes multiple passes through the data to get a result. This is a single pass method that calculates the **sample standard deviation**:

```
public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values)
{
    double mean = 0.0;
    double sum = 0.0;
    double stdDev = 0.0;
    int n = 0;
    foreach (double val in values)
    {
        n++;
        double delta = val - mean;
        mean += delta / n;
        sum += delta * (val - mean);
    }
    if (1 < n)
        stdDev = Math.Sqrt(sum / (n - 1));

    return stdDev;
}
```

This is the *sample standard deviation* since it divides by `n - 1`. For the normal standard deviation you need to divide by `n` instead.

This uses [Welford's method](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/70345/numerically-most-robust-way-to-compute-sum-of-products-standard-deviation-in-f) which has higher numerical accuracy compared to the `Average(x^2)-Average(x)^2` method.

Comment: You may not have iterated the entire sequence more than once, but your method will still make two calls to GetEnumerator (which could be triggering a complex SQL query).  Why not skip the condition and check n at the end of the loop?

Comment: Thanks Gideon, removes a level of nesting too. You're correct about the SQL, it's not relevant to what I'm working on so I hadn't considered the implication.

Comment: You're missing a definition of n.  Also it should be noted that dividing the sum by (n-1) instead of n makes this a sample standard deviation

Comment: Thanks Neil, added declaration for n and your point about sample standard deviation is noted.

Comment: To make this more carefully replicate the SQL method, I changed `this IEnumerable<double?> values` and `val in values.Where(val => val != null)`. Also, I will note that this method (Welford's method) is more accurate and faster than the method above.

Comment: I've edited your answer to make it clear that you're computing the **sample standard deviation**, not the normal **standard deviation**.

Comment: FYI the file link is Access Denied; I explored around and couldn't find a working version; update with working link if you can?

Comment: @jhaagsma looks like Warren has updated his blog platform https://warrenseen.com/blog and left some things behind. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 34):

This converts [David Clarke's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2878000/918414) into an extension that follows the same form as the other aggregate LINQ functions like Average.

Usage would be: `var stdev = data.StdDev(o => o.number)`

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static double StdDev<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, double> values)
    {
        // ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253874/linq-equivalent-for-standard-deviation
        // ref: http://warrenseen.com/blog/2006/03/13/how-to-calculate-standard-deviation/ 
        var mean = 0.0;
        var sum = 0.0;
        var stdDev = 0.0;
        var n = 0;
        foreach (var value in list.Select(values))
        {
            n++;
            var delta = value - mean;
            mean += delta / n;
            sum += delta * (value - mean);
        }
        if (1 < n)
            stdDev = Math.Sqrt(sum / (n - 1));

        return stdDev; 

    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `Average`/`Min`/`Max`/etc have overloads with and without selector functions. They also have overloads for integral types, float, etc.

Comment: for some reason I keep getting zeroes with this solution

Answer (score 6):

```
var stddev = Math.Sqrt(data.Average(z=>z*z)-Math.Pow(data.Average(),2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Straight to the point (and C# > 6.0), Dynamis answer becomes this:

```
    public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values)
    {
        var count = values?.Count() ?? 0;
        if (count <= 1) return 0;

        var avg = values.Average();
        var sum = values.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - avg, 2));

        return Math.Sqrt(sum / count);
    }
```

Edit 2020-08-27:

I took @David Clarke comments to make some performance tests
and this are the results:

```
    public static (double stdDev, double avg) StdDevFast(this List<double> values)
    {
        var count = values?.Count ?? 0;
        if (count <= 1) return (0, 0);

        var avg = GetAverage(values);
        var sum = GetSumOfSquareDiff(values, avg);

        return (Math.Sqrt(sum / count), avg);
    }

    private static double GetAverage(List<double> values)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++) 
            sum += values[i];
        
        return sum / values.Count;
    }
    private static double GetSumOfSquareDiff(List<double> values, double avg)
    {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
        {
            var diff = values[i] - avg;
            sum += diff * diff;
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

I tested this with a list of one million random doubles
the original implementation had an runtime of ~48ms
the performance optimized implementation 2-3ms
so this is an significant improvement.

Some interesting details:
getting rid of Math.Pow brings a boost of 33ms!
List instead of IEnumerable 6ms
manually Average calculation 4ms
For-loops instead of ForEach-loops 2ms
Array instead of List brings just an improvement of ~2% so i skipped this
using single instead of double brings nothing

Further lowering the code and using goto (yes GOTO... haven't used this since the 90s assembler...) instead of for-loops
does not pay, Thank goodness!

I have tested also parallel calculation, this makes sense on list > 200.000 items
It seems that Hardware and Software needs to initialize a lot and this is for small lists contra-productive.

All tests were executed two times in a row to get rid of the warmup-time.

Comment: Be aware this makes multiple passes through the data when evaluating `Count()`, `Average()`, and `Sum()`. That's ok for small values of `count` but has potential to impact performance if `count` is large.

Comment: @ david, so the simplest solution in my opinion would be to replace the signature with  `(this IList<double> values)`, performance tests would show the impact, and how many items make an significant difference

Comment: Yeah that doesn't solve the issue - those extension methods (`Count`, `Average`, `Sum`) each iterate the collection so you still have three full iterations to produce a result.

Answer (score 1):

Simple 4 lines, I used a List of doubles but one could use `IEnumerable<int> values`

```
public static double GetStandardDeviation(List<double> values)
{
    double avg = values.Average();
    double sum = values.Sum(v => (v - avg) * (v - avg));
    double denominator = values.Count - 1;
    return denominator > 0.0 ? Math.Sqrt(sum / denominator) : -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In *general* case we want to compute `StdDev` in *one pass*: what if `values` is *file* or RDBMS *cursor*
which can be *changed* between computing average and sum? We are going to have *inconsistent result*. The
code below uses just one pass:

```
// Population StdDev
public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values) {
  if (null == values)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

  double N = 0;
  double Sx = 0.0;
  double Sxx = 0.0;

  foreach (double x in values) {
    N += 1;
    Sx += x;
    Sxx += x * x;
  }

  return N == 0
    ? double.NaN // or throw exception
    : Math.Sqrt((Sxx - Sx * Sx / N) / N);
}
```

The very same idea for *sample* `StdDev`:

```
// Sample StdDev
public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<double> values) {
  if (null == values)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values));

  double N = 0;
  double Sx = 0.0;
  double Sxx = 0.0;

  foreach (double x in values) {
    N += 1;
    Sx += x;
    Sxx += x * x;
  }

  return N <= 1
    ? double.NaN // or throw exception
    : Math.Sqrt((Sxx - Sx * Sx / N) / (N - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double StdDev(this IEnumerable<int> values, bool as_sample = false)
{
    var count = values.Count();
    if (count > 0) // check for divide by zero
    // Get the mean.
    double mean = values.Sum() / count;

    // Get the sum of the squares of the differences
    // between the values and the mean.
    var squares_query =
        from int value in values
        select (value - mean) * (value - mean);
    double sum_of_squares = squares_query.Sum();
    return Math.Sqrt(sum_of_squares / (count - (as_sample ? 1 : 0)))
}
```

Comment: Note this is still making multiple passes through the data - ok if a small dataset but not good for large values of `count`.