# Calculate number of standard deviations from the mean

Tags: c#, asp.net, statistics

Here's what I have:

1. Standard Deviation
2. Mean
3. See code

   ```
   double[] series = { 150, 233, 80, 300, 200, 122, 125, 199, 255, 267, 102, 299 };
   double stdDev = CalculateStdDev(series);
   double mean = series.Average();
   ```

I need help to create a method to produce the following below:

1. For -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2 standard deviations from the mean calculate the count of where each fall
2. The result from number one should be in coordinate pairs like so: (-2, n), (-1, n), (0, n), (1, n), (2, n).

The purpose is to produce a normal curve or bell curve.

Example:

```
double mean = 194;
double neg2StdDevFromMean = mean - (2 * stdDev);
double negOneStdDevFromMean = mean - (1 * stdDev);
double negOneHalfStdDevFromMean = mean - (0.5 * stdDev);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question isn't all that clear, but maybe you want something like:

```
var query = from numStdDev in new[] { -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2 }
            select new             
            {
              NumStdDev = numStdDev,
              Value = mean + numStdDev * stdDev
            };
```

If by "co-ordinate pair", you're referring to `System.Drawing.PointF`, you can do:

```
var query = from numStdDev in new[] { -2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2 }
            select new PointF
                   ((float)numStdDev, (float)(mean + numStdDev * stdDev));
```

If you want help with calculating the standard deviation itself, you might want to look at: [LINQ Equivalent for Standard Deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253874/linq-equivalent-for-standard-deviation).

Comment: Sorry about that.  I basically need to plot a normal curve.

Comment: @subt13: Does my answer do what you want?

Comment: One moment I will try it out.  Thank you.