# How to get an array variable out of protected function and transfer it to another .cs file in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core, global-variables

My end goal is to transfer the array variable`double[] JumpDistanceArray` from ...\Difficulty\Skills\aim.cs to ...\Difficulty\OsuPerformanceCalculator.cs. Due to the variable being enclosed inside of a protected override function `protected override double StrainValueOf(DifficultyHitObject current)` I can't relate to it using `Skills.Aim.StrainValueOf.JumpDistanceArray.Average();` and I can't take it out of a protected state as well because that will cause a lot of chain reactions that I can't resolve, such as

> 'Aim.StrainValueOf(DifficultyHitObject)': cannot change access
>   modifiers when overriding 'protected' inherited member
>   'Skill.StrainValueOf(DifficultyHitObject)'
>   [osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu]csharp(CS0507)

I've tried many solutions suggested on this site but many solutions are too broad for me to understand correctly and implement into this specific type of problem.

Codes;
...\Difficulty\Skills\aim.cs

```
// Copyright (c) ppy Pty Ltd <contact@ppy.sh>. Licensed under the MIT Licence.
// See the LICENCE file in the repository root for full licence text.

using System;
using System.Linq;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Difficulty;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Difficulty.Preprocessing;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Difficulty.Skills;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Difficulty.Preprocessing;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Objects;
using static System.Math;

namespace osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Difficulty.Skills
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Represents the skill required to correctly aim at every object in the map with a uniform CircleSize and normalized distances.
    /// </summary>
    public class Aim : Skill
    {
        private const double angle_bonus_begin = Math.PI / 3;
        private const double timing_threshold = 107;
        private const double streamaimconst = 2.42;
        private const double stdevconst = 0.149820;
        /// public static double[] JumpDistanceArray;

        protected override double SkillMultiplier => 26.25;
        protected override double StrainDecayBase => 0.15;

        /// Standard Deviation Calculation Code courtesy of Roman http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/12/make-an-extension-method-that-calculates-standard-deviation-in-c/
        /// public static double GetStandardDeviation(List values)
        ///     {
        ///     double avg = values.Average();
        ///     double sum = values.Sum(v => (v - avg) * (v-avg));
        ///     double denominator = values.Count - 1;
        ///     return denominator > 0.0 ? Math.Sqrt(sum / denominator) : -1;
        ///     };
                /// Use JumpDistanceArray to calculate SD
                /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/5336708
                /// double average = JumpDistanceArray.Average();
                /// double sumOfSquaresOfDifferences = JumpDistanceArray.Select(val => (val - average) * (val - average)).Sum();
                /// double finalsd = Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquaresOfDifferences / JumpDistanceArray.Length); 
                /// double finalsdpp = finalsd/stdevconst when missCount = 0;

        protected override double StrainValueOf(DifficultyHitObject current)
        {
            if (current.BaseObject is Spinner)
                return 0;

            var osuCurrent = (OsuDifficultyHitObject)current;

            double result = 0;

            double sectionvelocity = osuCurrent.JumpDistance/osuCurrent.StrainTime;
            double[] JumpDistanceArray = new double[32767];
            if (sectionvelocity < streamaimconst) 
                { 
                    int jumpdistpointercount = 0;
                    JumpDistanceArray[jumpdistpointercount] = osuCurrent.JumpDistance;
                    jumpdistpointercount = jumpdistpointercount + 1;
                }

            if (Previous.Count > 0)
            {
                var osuPrevious = (OsuDifficultyHitObject)Previous[0];

                if (osuCurrent.Angle != null && osuCurrent.Angle.Value > angle_bonus_begin)
                {
                    const double scale = 90;

                    var angleBonus = Math.Sqrt(
                        Math.Max(osuPrevious.JumpDistance - scale, 0)
                        * Math.Pow(Math.Sin(osuCurrent.Angle.Value - angle_bonus_begin), 2)
                        * Math.Max(osuCurrent.JumpDistance - scale, 0));
                    result = 1.5 * applyDiminishingExp(Math.Max(0, angleBonus)) / Math.Max(timing_threshold, osuPrevious.StrainTime);
                }
            }

            double jumpDistanceExp = applyDiminishingExp(osuCurrent.JumpDistance);
            double travelDistanceExp = applyDiminishingExp(osuCurrent.TravelDistance);

            return Math.Max(
                result + (jumpDistanceExp + travelDistanceExp + Math.Sqrt(travelDistanceExp * jumpDistanceExp)) / Math.Max(osuCurrent.StrainTime, timing_threshold),
                (Math.Sqrt(travelDistanceExp * jumpDistanceExp) + jumpDistanceExp + travelDistanceExp) / osuCurrent.StrainTime
            );
        }

        private double applyDiminishingExp(double val) => Math.Pow(val, 0.99);
    }
}
```

...\Difficulty\OsuPerformanceCalculator.cs

```
// Copyright (c) ppy Pty Ltd <contact@ppy.sh>. Licensed under the MIT Licence.
// See the LICENCE file in the repository root for full licence text.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using osu.Game.Beatmaps;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Difficulty;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Difficulty.Preprocessing;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Difficulty.Skills;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Difficulty.Skills;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Mods;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Mods;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Objects;
using osu.Game.Rulesets.Scoring;
using osu.Game.Scoring;
using static System.Math;

namespace osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.Difficulty
{
    public class OsuPerformanceCalculator : PerformanceCalculator
    {
        public new OsuDifficultyAttributes Attributes => (OsuDifficultyAttributes)base.Attributes;

        private readonly int countHitCircles;
        private readonly int beatmapMaxCombo;

        private Mod[] mods;

        private double accuracy;
        private int scoreMaxCombo;
        private int countGreat;
        private int countGood;
        private int countMeh;
        private int countMiss;

        private const double streamaimconst = 2.42;
        private const double stdevconst = 0.149820;

        public OsuPerformanceCalculator(Ruleset ruleset, WorkingBeatmap beatmap, ScoreInfo score)
            : base(ruleset, beatmap, score)
        {
            countHitCircles = Beatmap.HitObjects.Count(h => h is HitCircle);

            beatmapMaxCombo = Beatmap.HitObjects.Count;
            // Add the ticks + tail of the slider. 1 is subtracted because the "headcircle" would be counted twice (once for the slider itself in the line above)
            beatmapMaxCombo += Beatmap.HitObjects.OfType<Slider>().Sum(s => s.NestedHitObjects.Count - 1);
        }

        public override double Calculate(Dictionary<string, double> categoryRatings = null)
        {
            mods = Score.Mods;
            accuracy = Score.Accuracy;
            scoreMaxCombo = Score.MaxCombo;
            countGreat = Convert.ToInt32(Score.Statistics[HitResult.Great]);
            countGood = Convert.ToInt32(Score.Statistics[HitResult.Good]);
            countMeh = Convert.ToInt32(Score.Statistics[HitResult.Meh]);
            countMiss = Convert.ToInt32(Score.Statistics[HitResult.Miss]);

            // Don't count scores made with supposedly unranked mods
            if (mods.Any(m => !m.Ranked))
                return 0;

            // Custom multipliers for NoFail and SpunOut.
            double multiplier = 1.12f; // This is being adjusted to keep the final pp value scaled around what it used to be when changing things

            if (mods.Any(m => m is OsuModNoFail))
                multiplier *= 0.90f;

            if (mods.Any(m => m is OsuModSpunOut))
                multiplier *= 0.95f;

            double aimValue = computeAimValue();
            double speedValue = computeSpeedValue();
            double accuracyValue = computeAccuracyValue();
            double totalValue =
                Math.Pow(
                    Math.Pow(aimValue, 1.1f) +
                    Math.Pow(speedValue, 1.1f) +
                    Math.Pow(accuracyValue, 1.1f), 1.0f / 1.1f
                ) * multiplier;

            if (categoryRatings != null)
            {
                categoryRatings.Add("Aim", aimValue);
                categoryRatings.Add("Speed", speedValue);
                categoryRatings.Add("Accuracy", accuracyValue);
                categoryRatings.Add("OD", Attributes.OverallDifficulty);
                categoryRatings.Add("AR", Attributes.ApproachRate);
                categoryRatings.Add("Max Combo", beatmapMaxCombo);
            }

            return totalValue;
        }

        private double computeAimValue()
        {
            /// var Aim = new Aim();
            double average = Skills.Aim.StrainValueOf.JumpDistanceArray.Average();
            double sumOfSquaresOfDifferences = Skills.Aim.StrainValueOf.JumpDistanceArray.Select(val => (val - average) * (val - average)).Sum();
            double finalsd = Math.Sqrt(sumOfSquaresOfDifferences / Skills.Aim.StrainValueOf.JumpDistanceArray.Length); 
            double finalsdpp = 0;
            if (countMiss == 0) 
                  finalsdpp = finalsdpp+(finalsd/stdevconst);
            double rawAim = Attributes.AimStrain + finalsdpp;

            if (mods.Any(m => m is OsuModTouchDevice))
                rawAim = Math.Pow(rawAim, 0.8);

            double aimValue = Math.Pow(5.0f * Math.Max(1.0f, rawAim / 0.0675f) - 4.0f, 3.0f) / 100000.0f;

            // Longer maps are worth more
            double lengthBonus = 0.95f + 0.4f * Math.Min(1.0f, totalHits / 2000.0f) +
                                 (totalHits > 2000 ? Math.Log10(totalHits / 2000.0f) * 0.5f : 0.0f);

            aimValue *= lengthBonus;

            // Penalize misses exponentially. This mainly fixes tag4 maps and the likes until a per-hitobject solution is available
            aimValue *= Math.Pow(0.97f, countMiss);

            // Combo scaling
            if (beatmapMaxCombo > 0)
                aimValue *= Math.Min(Math.Pow(scoreMaxCombo, 0.8f) / Math.Pow(beatmapMaxCombo, 0.8f), 1.0f);

            double approachRateFactor = 1.0f;

            if (Attributes.ApproachRate > 10.33f)
                approachRateFactor += 0.3f * (Attributes.ApproachRate - 10.33f);
            else if (Attributes.ApproachRate < 8.0f)
            {
                approachRateFactor += 0.01f * (8.0f - Attributes.ApproachRate);
            }

            aimValue *= approachRateFactor;

            // We want to give more reward for lower AR when it comes to aim and HD. This nerfs high AR and buffs lower AR.
            if (mods.Any(h => h is OsuModHidden))
                aimValue *= 1.0f + 0.04f * (12.0f - Attributes.ApproachRate);

            if (mods.Any(h => h is OsuModFlashlight))
            {
                // Apply object-based bonus for flashlight.
                aimValue *= 1.0f + 0.35f * Math.Min(1.0f, totalHits / 200.0f) +
                            (totalHits > 200
                                ? 0.3f * Math.Min(1.0f, (totalHits - 200) / 300.0f) +
                                  (totalHits > 500 ? (totalHits - 500) / 1200.0f : 0.0f)
                                : 0.0f);
            }

            // Scale the aim value with accuracy _slightly_
            aimValue *= 0.5f + accuracy / 2.0f;
            // It is important to also consider accuracy difficulty when doing that
            aimValue *= 0.98f + Math.Pow(Attributes.OverallDifficulty, 2) / 2500;

            return aimValue;
        }

        private double computeSpeedValue()
        {
            double speedValue = Math.Pow(5.0f * Math.Max(1.0f, Attributes.SpeedStrain / 0.0675f) - 4.0f, 3.0f) / 100000.0f;

            // Longer maps are worth more
            speedValue *= 0.95f + 0.4f * Math.Min(1.0f, totalHits / 2000.0f) +
                          (totalHits > 2000 ? Math.Log10(totalHits / 2000.0f) * 0.5f : 0.0f);

            // Penalize misses exponentially. This mainly fixes tag4 maps and the likes until a per-hitobject solution is available
            speedValue *= Math.Pow(0.97f, countMiss);

            // Combo scaling
            if (beatmapMaxCombo > 0)
                speedValue *= Math.Min(Math.Pow(scoreMaxCombo, 0.8f) / Math.Pow(beatmapMaxCombo, 0.8f), 1.0f);

            double approachRateFactor = 1.0f;
            if (Attributes.ApproachRate > 10.33f)
                approachRateFactor += 0.3f * (Attributes.ApproachRate - 10.33f);

            speedValue *= approachRateFactor;

            if (mods.Any(m => m is OsuModHidden))
                speedValue *= 1.0f + 0.04f * (12.0f - Attributes.ApproachRate);

            // Scale the speed value with accuracy _slightly_
            speedValue *= 0.02f + accuracy;
            // It is important to also consider accuracy difficulty when doing that
            speedValue *= 0.96f + Math.Pow(Attributes.OverallDifficulty, 2) / 1600;

            return speedValue;
        }

        private double computeAccuracyValue()
        {
            // This percentage only considers HitCircles of any value - in this part of the calculation we focus on hitting the timing hit window
            double betterAccuracyPercentage;
            int amountHitObjectsWithAccuracy = countHitCircles;

            if (amountHitObjectsWithAccuracy > 0)
                betterAccuracyPercentage = ((countGreat - (totalHits - amountHitObjectsWithAccuracy)) * 6 + countGood * 2 + countMeh) / (amountHitObjectsWithAccuracy * 6);
            else
                betterAccuracyPercentage = 0;

            // It is possible to reach a negative accuracy with this formula. Cap it at zero - zero points
            if (betterAccuracyPercentage < 0)
                betterAccuracyPercentage = 0;

            // Lots of arbitrary values from testing.
            // Considering to use derivation from perfect accuracy in a probabilistic manner - assume normal distribution
            double accuracyValue = Math.Pow(1.52163f, Attributes.OverallDifficulty) * Math.Pow(betterAccuracyPercentage, 24) * 2.83f;

            // Bonus for many hitcircles - it's harder to keep good accuracy up for longer
            accuracyValue *= Math.Min(1.15f, Math.Pow(amountHitObjectsWithAccuracy / 1000.0f, 0.3f));

            if (mods.Any(m => m is OsuModHidden))
                accuracyValue *= 1.08f;
            if (mods.Any(m => m is OsuModFlashlight))
                accuracyValue *= 1.02f;

            return accuracyValue;
        }

        private double totalHits => countGreat + countGood + countMeh + countMiss;
        private double totalSuccessfulHits => countGreat + countGood + countMeh;
    }
}
```

P.S. For people who want to get the original full project folder:  https://github.com/ppy/osu/tree/59a5df8bcac3d7b7d68b6bc04e11d0fcc9d4b94f/osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu/Difficulty

Comment: Create a public method to return the private data.

Comment: @jdweng I don't know how to do that. Can you please broadly guide me how to do it?

Comment: public double[] GetJumpDistanceArray() { return JumpDistanceArray;}

Comment: @jdweng Should I place it outside or inside of the protected function?

Comment: It should be in the class outside any other methods.

Comment: @jdweng Difficulty\Skills\Aim.cs(86,57): error CS0103: The name 'JumpDistanceArray' does not exist in the current context [C:\Users\Korn\osu-tools\osu\osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu\osu.Game.Rulesets.Osu.csproj]

Comment: The code should be in the Aim class.

Comment: @jdweng Already in Aim class, neither before nor after the protected function removes the error.

Comment: You need to call the method by the instance of the class.