# LINQ to SQL - calling built-in aggregate functions (i.e. STDEV)

Tags: c#, sql, linq, aggregate-functions, standard-deviation

Is there any way to have LINQ translate queries directly to functions like SQL's `STDEV`? For example, the LINQ

```
from t in table
group t by t.something into g
select new {
    avg = g.Average(o => o.number)
    stdev = g.?????
}
```

gets turned into a SQL `AVG`. However, there is no support for standard deviation in LINQ.

One approach was suggested here:
[Standard Deviation in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253874/linq-equivalent-for-standard-deviation)

However, this is clunky and it also requires a bit of additional work to handle possible null values, which the sql `STDEV` function automatically ignores for you. Additionally, it results in less data being sent over the wire and it's faster to compute.

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no way to do it directly through LINQ.

You could create a [CLR aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131057.aspx) which really just wraps the [`STDEV` aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190474.aspx) in SQL Server, but that would be a ton of excessive work (although it *is* possible).

However, the option of least resistance is going to be for each query that you want the standard deviation on, you would create a stored procedure which performs the operations and then use LINQ-to-SQL to call that.

Or, if you want to use composition in LINQ-to-SQL, you can [create a user-defined table function in SQL server and then access that in LINQ-to-SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386954.aspx) and compose your query using that.

Comment: I ended up going with a stored procedure. Thanks.