# Probability Density Function of a list

Tags: c#, probability-density

Is there a class in the standard library of .NET that, given an `IEnumerable<T>` (e.g., `List<double>`) will assign a `random` positive probability (probability density function) to each value so that the result follows a Gaussian distribution?

So for example, given a `List<double>`, I want a new `List<double>` whose range is 2-standard deviations above and below the min and max values of the original list, by some increment `n` (e.g, .01, .25, etc), and assigns positive probabilities to that much larger list, such that the new list probabilities are Gaussian.

Comment: *"in the standard library of .NET"* - No.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Standard Deviation in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253874/standard-deviation-in-linq)

Comment: By Standard.Net I also mean Accord.Net and Mathnet.Numerics. Those libraries are so vast I often have no idea how to find anything.

Comment: A standard deviation is not the same thing as a PDF.

Comment: Note that the Gaussian distribution has no minimum or maximum, so your problem is ill-defined.