# SQuirreL database, and standard deviation

Tags: sqlite, squirrel-sql

I'm using Python to load data into an embedded SQLite database (i.e. just an SQLite file).  Following that, I'm using SQuirreL to connect to the file and analyze the data.

I'd like to be able to use standard deviation as part of my analysis, but SQLite doesn't support this.

I've been able to download and compile the "extension-functions.c" into a DLL, but I'm stuck on figuring out what to do next (or if that's even the right way to go).

I've seen some posts on creating a STDEV function from Python for SQLite, but I don't think that helps for my SQuirreL client (unless an SQLite file created with this function retains such capability when accessed by SQuirreL...?).

Comment: I never used SQuirreL, but I would look if SQuirreL could calculate the S.D. for you. If it's open source you can add the method or it might have a plug-in model that lets you add the functionality of calculating standard deviation for a data set. I think that you should look at what SQuirreL can do, especially if that is meant for analysis it should be able to make calculations. You should alternatively be able to use SQL to calculate standard deviation. That could be a little work but should be possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298339/standard-deviation-for-sqlite

Comment: Check if SQuirreL allows you to use [load_extension()](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension).