# calculating mean and standard deviation of the data which does not fit in memory using python

Tags: python, statistics

I have a lot of data stored at disk in large arrays. I cant load everything in memory altogether.

How one could calculate the mean and the standard deviation?

Comment: @Joni, Please read it carefully, in that question the data could be loaded in the memory, my question is when we cant load all the data, thats why the questions are not similar

Comment: The algorithms are the same.

Comment: @Joni, it does not matter, there are many problems which could be solved using same algorithms in different perspectives, so it means whenever somebody wants to search for mean and variance for big dataset, would he be searching the title "How to efficiently calculate a running standard deviation?", do you think that somebidy will write this query or the one asked in my question?

Comment: @Joni, Please try to understand the semantics!!!

Comment: Shan, the online algorithm for calculating the mean and variance is the same whether the dataset fits into memory or not. This question already has an answer in the linked question, and in dozens of other questions on this same topic.

Comment: Perhaps this question would serve as a better duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543651/computing-standard-deviation-in-a-stream

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a simple [online algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_algorithm) that computes both the mean and the variance by looking at each datapoint once and using `O(1)` memory.

Wikipedia [offers the following code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Online_algorithm):

```
def online_variance(data):
    n = 0
    mean = 0
    M2 = 0

    for x in data:
        n = n + 1
        delta = x - mean
        mean = mean + delta/n
        M2 = M2 + delta*(x - mean)

    variance = M2/(n - 1)
    return variance
```

This algorithm is also known as [Welford's method](http://www.johndcook.com/standard_deviation.html). Unlike the method suggested in the other answer, it can be shown to have [nice numerical properties](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/).

Take the square root of the variance to get the standard deviation.

Comment: So I am curious: how does this work if not all data can be in memory at once? Is the assumption that `data` is an iterator that yields the next item until there is no more, and that it pages in more items from disk?

Comment: @hughdbrown: The code is just an illustration. For example, `data` could be a generator, or a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a math question. For the mean, you know that you can take the mean of a chunk of data, and then take the mean of the means. If the chunks aren't the same size, you'll have to take a weighted average.

For the standard deviation, you'll have to calculate the variance first. I'd suggest doing this alongside the calculation of the mean. For variance, you have

Var(X) = Avg(X^2) - Avg(X)^2

So compute the average of your data, and the average of your (data^2). Aggregate them as above, and the take the difference.

Then the standard deviation is just the square root of the variance.

Note that you could do the whole thing with iterators, which is probably the most efficient.

Comment: The algorithm you suggest for calculating the variance is numerically unstable and the results it produces are inaccurate or even completely wrong for large datasets. See for example http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/, or the Wikipedia page on algorithms for computing variance.

Comment: @Joni, that's not quite right. Reading your link, the assumption is that the mean is much greater than the variance, which is not at all surprising, given the difference of squares in the formula. It looks like the difference between the mean and variance has to be several orders of magnitude before this is an issue.

Comment: On a careful read, you are right. If you calculate the running *average* of X^2 (rather than the sum, which I see often) you won't have problems with big datasets.