# Numpy - Normalize RGB image dataset

Tags: python, image, numpy, machine-learning, data-processing

My dataset is a Numpy array with dimensions (N, W, H, C), where N is the number of images, H and W are height and width respectively and C is the number of channels.

I know that there are many tools out there but I would like to normalize the images with only Numpy.

My plan is to compute the mean and standard deviation across the whole dataset for each of the three channels and then subtract the mean and divide by the standard deviation.

Suppose we have two images in the dataset and and the first channel of those two images looks like this:

```
x=array([[[3., 4.],
          [5., 6.]],

          [[1., 2.],
          [3., 4.]]])
```

Compute the mean:

```
numpy.mean(x[:,:,:,0])
= 3.5
```

Compute the std:

```
numpy.std(x[:,:,:,0])
= 1.5
```

Normalize the first channel:

```
x[:,:,:,0] = (x[:,:,:,0] - 3.5) / 1.5
```

Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks good, but there are some things NumPy does that could make it nicer. I'm assuming that you want to normalize each channel separately.

For one, notice that `x` has a method `mean`, so we can write `x[..., 0].mean()` instead of `np.mean(x[:, :, :, 0])`. Also, the `mean` method takes the keyword argument `axis`, which we can use as follows:

```py
means = x.mean(axis=(0, 1, 2)) # Take the mean over the N,H,W axes
means.shape # => will evaluate to (C,)
```

Then we can subtract the means from the whole dataset like so:

```py
centered = x - x.mean(axis=(0,1,2), keepdims=True)
```

Note that we had to use `keepdims` here.

There is also an `x.std` that works the same way, so we can do the whole normalization in 1 line:

```py
z = (x - x.mean(axis=(0,1,2), keepdims=True)) / x.std(axis=(0,1,2), keepdims=True)
```

Check out the docs for [numpy.ndarray.mean](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html) and [np.ndarray.std](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.std.html) for more info. The `np.ndarray.method` methods are what you hit when you call `x.method` instead of using `np.method(x)` instead.

---

Edit: I have since learned that, of course, there is a [`scipy.stats.zscore`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.zscore.html). I'm not sure if this is a more readable way to take zscores along each channel, but some might prefer it:

```
z = zscore(x.reshape(-1, 3)).reshape(x.shape)
```

The scipy function operates only over a single axis, so we have to reshape into an `NHW x C` matrix first and then reshape back.

Comment: Great answer, would only suggest to link to the docs for Numpy so interested parties can read up on what the docs have to say about the parameters.

Comment: what if the entire dataset does not fint into memory?

Comment: It's possible to compute the mean and standard deviation in a rolling or online fashion without loading the whole dataset into memory at once -- there are a million SO questions and other sources that describe this, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15638612/calculating-mean-and-standard-deviation-of-the-data-which-does-not-fit-in-memory. Then you can just plug the mean and standard deviation in place of `x.mean(...)` and `x.std(...)` above when you load up a portion of the data from disk for later use.

Comment: I didn't know about the keepdims option, very useful, thanks!