# Python: cannot evaluate mean and standard deviation of huge tensor

Tags: python, numpy, std, mean, tensor

I am trying to evaluate mean and stand deviation of a list of two huge tensors, with dimensions (79000, 128, 8, 75), for a total of 6067200000 elements. 
The problem is that, while the calculation of the mean with np.mean is just slow, when I evaluate the standard deviation with np.std the server gets stuck, probably I am running out of memory. Do you know any "smarter" way to evaluate mean and standard deviation? Thanks.

Comment: There's a wonderful article linked in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543651/computing-standard-deviation-in-a-stream) that may help you.  I am not sure if there is an implementation available that you can use.

Comment: following that article above maybe break it down? use `reduce` to get the sum of all elements, `len` to get the number of elements, etc...

Comment: I am using [this version](https://gist.github.com/alexalemi/2151722) of Welford's method for Python, didn't improve much, the server still gets stuck. I have also tested the `reduce` function for a simple sum of elements on a list with the same number of elements, still slow.

Comment: Solved: shortly, I am using a code that updates the mean and the standard deviation every time the tensor is filled with a new chunk of data, basically it is a running calculation.