# How to find average of list in a column in pyspark?

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, mean

I have dataframe that looks like the following. I want to be able to find an average and put in a new_column. I can find avg using udf, but cannot put it in a column. It would be nice, if you can help without udf. Otherwise, any help with current solution is welcome.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField 
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, ArrayType
data = [
("Smith","[55, 65, 75]"),
("Anna","[33, 44, 55]"),
("Williams","[9.5, 4.5, 9.7]"),    
]
     
schema = StructType([
StructField('name', StringType(), True),
StructField('some_value', StringType(), True)
])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema= schema)
df.show(truncate=False)

+--------+---------------+
|name    |some_value     |
+--------+---------------+
|Smith   |[55, 65, 75]   |
|Anna    |[33, 44, 55]   |
|Williams|[9.5, 4.5, 9.7]|
+--------+---------------+
```

A solution is like this,

```
array_mean = F.udf(lambda x: float(np.mean(x)), FloatType())
```

(from [Find mean of pyspark array<double>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55502546/find-mean-of-pyspark-arraydouble)) returns a dataframe not a new column.

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You have a string column that looks like an array, instead of an array column, so you need to convert the datatype in the UDF as well:

```
import json
import numpy as np
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

array_mean = F.udf(lambda x: float(np.mean(json.loads(x))), 'float')
df2 = df.withColumn('mean_value', array_mean('some_value'))

df2.show()
+--------+---------------+----------+
|    name|     some_value|mean_value|
+--------+---------------+----------+
|   Smith|   [55, 65, 75]|      65.0|
|    Anna|   [33, 44, 55]|      44.0|
|Williams|[9.5, 4.5, 9.7]|       7.9|
+--------+---------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming from Pandasand newbie to pyspark, I went the long way.

1. Strip []
2. split to turn into list
3. explode
4. mean

   ```
   df2 = df.select(df.name,F.regexp_replace('some_value', '[\\]\\[]', "").alias("some_value")).select(df.name, F.split("some_value",",").alias("some_value")).select(df.name, F.explode("some_value").alias("some_value"))
    df2 = df2.withColumn("some_value", df2.some_value.cast('float')).groupBy("name").mean( "some_value")
   ```